# ä letter sorting problem in Java

Tags: java, sorting, unicode, localization

Hi have some piece of code :

```
Collator col = Collator.getInstance(Locale.GERMAN);

List< String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("ac");
list.add("äb");
list.add("aa");
list.add("bb");


Collections.sort(list,col);
System.out.println(list);
```

I would expect to get [aa, ac, äb, bb] output, instead I am getting :
[aa, äb, ac, bb]

I have no idea what I am doing wrong ... thanks in advance for help.

---

Hi thanks all for answers.

Unfortunately requirements of the project say clearly that strings must be sorted in such order : 
[aa, ac, äb, bb] : so I tried to use this code :

```
 String europeanRules =
        ("< a,A ; \u00e0,\u00c0 ; \u00e1,\u00c1 ; \u00e2,\u00c2 ; \u00e3,\u00c3; \u00e4,\u00c4 ; \u00e5,\u00c5 ; \u00e6,\u00c6 "+
                "; \u0101,\u0100 ; \u0103,\u0102 ; \u0105,\u0104 " +       
         "< b,B < c,C ; \u00e7,\u00c7 ; \u0107,\u0106 ; \u0109,\u0108 ; \u010b,\u010a ; \u010d,\u010c " +
         "< d,D ; \u010f,\u010e ; \u0111,\u0110 " +
         "< e,E ; \u00e8,\u00c8 ; \u00e9,\u00c9 ; \u00ea,\u00ca ; \u00eb,\u00cb " +
             "; \u0113,\u0112 ; \u0115,\u0114 ; \u0116,\u0117 ; \u0119,\u0118 ; \u011b,\u011a " +
         "< f,F < g,G < h,H " +
         "< i,I ; \u00ec,\u00cc ; \u00ed,\u00cd ; \u00ee,\u00ce ; \u00ef,\u00cf " +
         "< j,J < k,K " +
         "< l,L ; \u013a,\u0139 ; \u013c,\u013b ; \u013e,\u013d ; \u0140,\u013f ; \u0142,\u0141 " +
         "< m,M < n,N ; \u00f1,\u00d1 ; \u0144,\u0143 ; \u0146,\u0145 ; \u0148,\u0147 " +
         "< o,O ; \u00f2,\u00d2 ; \u00f3,\u00d3 ; \u00f4,\u00d4 ; \u00f5,\u00d5 ; \u00f6,\u00d6 ; \u00f8,\u00d8 " +
             "; \u014d,\u014c ; \u014f,\u014e ; \u0151,\u0150 " +
         "< p,P < q,Q < r,R ; \u0155,\u0154 ; \u0157,\u0156 ; \u0159,\u0158 " +
         "< s,S ; \u015b,\u015a ; \u015d,\u015c ; \u015f,\u015e ; \u0161,\u0160 " +
         "< t,T ; \u0163,\u0162 ; \u0165,\u0164 ; \u0167,\u0166 " +
         "< u,U ; \u00f9,\u00d9 ; \u00fa,\u00da ; \u00fb,\u00db ; \u00fc,\u00dc ; \u0169,\u0168 ; \u016b,\u016a ; \u016d,\u016c " +
             "; \u016f,\u016e ; \u0171,\u0170 ; \u0173,\u0172 " +
         "< v,V < w,W ; \u0175,\u0174 " +
         "< x,X < y,Y ; \u00fd,\u00dd ; \u00ff ; \u0177,\u0176 ; \u0178 " +
         "< z,Z ; \u017a,\u0179 ; \u017c,\u017b ; \u017e,\u017d");      

    RuleBasedCollator col = null;
    try {
        col = new RuleBasedCollator(europeanRules);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
    }   
    col.setStrength(Collator.SECONDARY);
    col.setDecomposition(Collator.FULL_DECOMPOSITION);

    List< String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("ac");
    list.add("äb");
    list.add("aa");
    list.add("bb");     
    Collections.sort(list,col);
    System.out.println(list);
```

00E4 is UTF-8 code for ä so as I understand it should work ok ? Or I am doing something wrong ... thanks in advance for help.

Comment: I suspect in the German locale it doesn't count umlauts as making-another-character. Try in English/US -- although I'm not sure how that will work with the unicode decorations either.

Comment: Why would you expect it in that order?

Comment: should `äb` be sorted before `af` or after?

Comment: You need to understand how Unicode collation works.  The default sort will not consider diacritics at the first comparison level, as "ab" and "áb" and "äb" will all precede "ac". Also, the German phonebook locale (which isn't the one you are using!) will treat "äb" as equivalent to "aeb". You sometimes need this per German rules.

Comment: Also, if your source code were itself in UTF-8, this would be a lot easier to read!

Answer (score 8):

The order you get is correct, at least according to the [Wikipedia entry](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alphabetische_Sortierung) for this subject (sorry in German, [Google Translate](http://translate.google.com/translate?js=n&prev=_t&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&layout=2&eotf=1&sl=de&tl=en&u=http%3A%2F%2Fde.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FAlphabetische_Sortierung) might help you, although it corrupts the umlauts for me...)

Comment: you are right. The sort order **is** correct. `ä` is sorted like `ae`

Comment: But shouldn't `äb` (`aeb`) come after `ac` then?

Comment: Well, according Wikipedia, there are two variants in the standard DIN 5007: the first one (to be used for words) treats ä and a as the same, the second one (to be used for names) treats ä and ae as the same. Java seems to implement the first one, which I find sensible.

Answer (score 2):

If you want your accented characters to always come after the normal ones, you can prepend an `@` in your defined rule for the [RuleBasedCollator](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/text/RuleBasedCollator.html).

> The definitions of the rule elements is as follows:
>
> [...]
>
> **Modifier**: There are currently two modifiers that turn on special collation rules.
>
> '**@**' : Turns on backwards sorting of accents (secondary differences), as in French.
>
> '**!**' : Turns on Thai/Lao vowel-consonant swapping. If this rule is in force when a Thai vowel of the range \U0E40-\U0E44 precedes a Thai consonant of the range \U0E01-\U0E2E OR a Lao vowel of the range \U0EC0-\U0EC4 precedes a Lao consonant of the range \U0E81-\U0EAE then the vowel is placed after the consonant for collation purposes.
>
> [...]

So your sample code would look like follows:

(I made the change only for the `ä` character, i.e. `@\u00e4, @\u00c4`)

```
 String europeanRules =
        ("< a,A ; \u00e0,\u00c0 ; \u00e1,\u00c1 ; \u00e2,\u00c2 ; \u00e3,\u00c3; @\u00e4,@\u00c4 ; \u00e5,\u00c5 ; \u00e6,\u00c6 "+
                "; \u0101,\u0100 ; \u0103,\u0102 ; \u0105,\u0104 " +       
         "< b,B < c,C ; \u00e7,\u00c7 ; \u0107,\u0106 ; \u0109,\u0108 ; \u010b,\u010a ; \u010d,\u010c " +
         "< d,D ; \u010f,\u010e ; \u0111,\u0110 " +
         "< e,E ; \u00e8,\u00c8 ; \u00e9,\u00c9 ; \u00ea,\u00ca ; \u00eb,\u00cb " +
             "; \u0113,\u0112 ; \u0115,\u0114 ; \u0116,\u0117 ; \u0119,\u0118 ; \u011b,\u011a " +
         "< f,F < g,G < h,H " +
         "< i,I ; \u00ec,\u00cc ; \u00ed,\u00cd ; \u00ee,\u00ce ; \u00ef,\u00cf " +
         "< j,J < k,K " +
         "< l,L ; \u013a,\u0139 ; \u013c,\u013b ; \u013e,\u013d ; \u0140,\u013f ; \u0142,\u0141 " +
         "< m,M < n,N ; \u00f1,\u00d1 ; \u0144,\u0143 ; \u0146,\u0145 ; \u0148,\u0147 " +
         "< o,O ; \u00f2,\u00d2 ; \u00f3,\u00d3 ; \u00f4,\u00d4 ; \u00f5,\u00d5 ; \u00f6,\u00d6 ; \u00f8,\u00d8 " +
             "; \u014d,\u014c ; \u014f,\u014e ; \u0151,\u0150 " +
         "< p,P < q,Q < r,R ; \u0155,\u0154 ; \u0157,\u0156 ; \u0159,\u0158 " +
         "< s,S ; \u015b,\u015a ; \u015d,\u015c ; \u015f,\u015e ; \u0161,\u0160 " +
         "< t,T ; \u0163,\u0162 ; \u0165,\u0164 ; \u0167,\u0166 " +
         "< u,U ; \u00f9,\u00d9 ; \u00fa,\u00da ; \u00fb,\u00db ; \u00fc,\u00dc ; \u0169,\u0168 ; \u016b,\u016a ; \u016d,\u016c " +
             "; \u016f,\u016e ; \u0171,\u0170 ; \u0173,\u0172 " +
         "< v,V < w,W ; \u0175,\u0174 " +
         "< x,X < y,Y ; \u00fd,\u00dd ; \u00ff ; \u0177,\u0176 ; \u0178 " +
         "< z,Z ; \u017a,\u0179 ; \u017c,\u017b ; \u017e,\u017d");      
    
    RuleBasedCollator col = null;
    try {
        col = new RuleBasedCollator(europeanRules);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
    }   
    col.setStrength(Collator.SECONDARY);
    col.setDecomposition(Collator.FULL_DECOMPOSITION);
    
    List< String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("ac");
    list.add("äb");
    list.add("aa");
    list.add("af");
    list.add("bb");     
    Collections.sort(list,col);
    System.out.println(list);
```

The output is:

```
[aa, ac, af, äb, bb]
```